# Typescript: get exact type of variable

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Having an object like

```
const translations = {
  say_hello: 'hello {{name}}',
};
```

I'd like to extract the **exact** type of the object, like

```
type Translations = {
  say_hello: 'hello {{name}}',
}
```

So far I'm playing around something like

```
type GetExactType<T> = {[K in keyof T]-?: T[K]};
```

but it doesn't work as expected, because

```
  GetExactType<typeof translations>;
```

resolves to

```
{
   say_hello: string,
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't do it *after* that initialization of `translations`; the information you want has already been discarded.  You can *change* the type of the initializer via a  [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mZjeam) but I don't know if that meets your needs.

Comment: You want `GetExactType<typeof translations>` to return `Translations`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `as const` but that results in `readonly` on everything, which might not be desirable.

Instead, you could have a function to narrow it for you:

```
type Narrow<T> =
    | (T extends infer U ? U : never)
    | Extract<T, number | string | boolean | bigint | symbol | null | undefined | []>
    | ([T] extends [[]] ? [] : { [K in keyof T]: Narrow<T[K]> });

function narrow<T>(t: Narrow<T>): T {
    return t as T;
}
```

And then when you use it, it'll infer the types for you:

```
const translations = narrow({
  say_hello: 'hello {{name}}',
});

type T = typeof translations;
//   ^? { say_hello: 'hello {{name}}'; }
```

Note that it is impossible to retrieve the original type after you define it like this:

```
const translations = {
  say_hello: 'hello {{name}}',
};
```

so some sort of direct operation on the value before it is assigned is required.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcghgJwQewO4B4AqA+KBeAWACgpSoAfKACkyggA9gIA7AEwGcoBLZgMwgRQAqlAD8wqAC4ozCADcBASmJkKUAKKMEcAMbAsAGhkBXALYAjAWvbAEPAOZrzyZABsIcZk672ewayAWbmrMxq6uasZsELw8EKxqANoAutgqZJRUiZjJdIwsHFCJKbniKVJQAN5FANLcXgDWECDIvFA50vBIaFiJNalQAL6KANzExLxRelzIXsyIKBg4VMCdCz04itK0lemkCBDAxghe-nCcmGNEg+NEOrM2ULae7K5wwDPMnHgy66hUuxIUHYcBAAH0ABYQcLIaQAcihMKqlXmpggg0GcIMxGGV2IoEg7XwT3AEFaT20XzeHweVwA9HSyAA9URAA)

Comment: Fascinating. I suspect, given this is what appears to be translation strings, the `as const` would be sufficient. But really cool to have that `Narrow` type in the toolkit...

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell TypeScript that the `say_hello` property's type is `'hello {{name}}'`, not `string`. There are at least a couple of ways to do that:

1. Via `as const`, saying that the object won't change:

   ```typescript
   const translations = {
       say_hello: 'hello {{name}}',
   } as const;
   //^^^^^^^^
   type Translations = typeof translations;
   ```
2. Explicitly:

   ```typescript
   const translations = {
       say_hello: 'hello {{name}}' as 'hello {{name}}',
   // −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   };
   type Translations = typeof translations;
   ```

   (but...ewww...)

   or

   ```typescript
   const translations: { say_hello: 'hello {{name}}' } = {
       say_hello: 'hello {{name}}',
   };
   type Translations = typeof translations;
   // (But if you were going to do that, you'd just want to write the type
   // alias manually and then apply it to the `translations` constant, rather
   // than doing it this way around.)
   ```

I use the `as const` for things like translation strings all the time.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFBOBDSAbRUCW4IEYYF4YBvAWACgZKYJEBPAfQAsBTFFEALhgCIW2RiRMIgC2zAL7juMRBB592g4WMncANOXEBuclFoAHZjAAqSVOiyQ8hPYZAAzOGYhpM2HDrIB6L1QB6APzk5KCQsAjILhbYAExcRNR0TKzsXLwpAkRCohJSMOIExORUiQwKnPIZSjmqGmTaugZGppGulhAxhbbMDk6t0ZAxnj7+Qd6+ABQAQgCusBiOtCAzMADuzPBGAOYgGGBbcAIAJgJQjOhqMEszAORHMABWM9BryOECq-AYUEZnv03kEaIFAYWQwETIGbAlC0GRge5-MAyfT6GEwb6HOAsGAAAwi5jckBxMFC0DelyQf3ggN8Z2QMBOewOGLOGDkqzoMngy3hADoAJTBMik8LONrYADMhVIFCoNDKGTS5WqKikdQKYJFnkahhMYoGEClNiavXxUUJhuGvkogXIQA)